# Config Jenkins Workspace Root Directory

Tags: ios, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I created new project and using Jenkins to build it.
So, everything is ok if I put the project in directory belongs to Jenkins user.
My config for Workspace Root Directory is:

```
${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/workspace
```

Home Jenkins user is

```
/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home
```

However, if I change this config to use new workspace under other user home directory (in my case is /Users/apple), I receive this error:

```
Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs
java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs
    at hudson.FilePath.mkdirs(FilePath.java:1164)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1268)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1741)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:410)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I also tried config to this path, but it also no lucky:

```
${ITEM_ROOTDIR}/../../../../../../apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs
```

So, how can I config to use with another checkout source directory?
Example, I checkout my source to this folder:

```
 /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs
```

and I want to use this folder as workspace, how I do it?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can actually see the error is with permissions:

`Failed to mkdirs: /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs`

The job is failing to create the folder structure on the given location.

Your options:

- Pre-create the folders and grant access to the service running the job:

  `sudo mkdir /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs`

(given Jenkins uses account 'jenkins') `sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs`

- Use a different location for your workspace which is not restricted like a user profile.

Comment: No any lucky @freebourn, I forgot to explain that I've already change permission to every one can write, but it had the same issue.
Can you suggest to me any document to step thís, I've searched on forum and I think all of its were messy.

Comment: Can you provide output of 'ls -la /Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs'?

Comment: Apples-MacBook-Pro:~ HocTran$ ls -la ~/Desktop/JenkinsJobs/
total 16  
drwxrwxr-x   5 jenkins  jenkins   170 Nov  8 22:34 .  
drwx------+ 57 HocTran  staff    1938 Nov  8 22:32 ..  
-rwxrwxr-x@  1 jenkins  jenkins  6148 Nov  8 21:08 .DS_Store  
drwxrwxr-x   2 HocTran  jenkins    68 Nov  8 22:34 MyJenkinsCustomWorkspace  
drwxrwxr-x   2 HocTran  jenkins    68 Nov  8 22:33 builds

Comment: Can you check if the user running jenkins is indeed 'jenkins' ? 
You can check that by running 'ps aux' on terminal and finding the jenkins process. in some versions its 'hudson'

Comment: IF the account running jenkins is indeed 'jenkins' and not something different, can you try the following command:
'chmod -R 777  ~/Desktop/JenkinsJobs/' if it still doesn't work we will eliminate the possibility of this being a permission issue.

Comment: I've checked it, it's 'jenkins', not 'hudson'.

Comment: Also, the same result if change the directory to 777 mode.

Comment: Can you please try the following:
1) Put absolute path in job's workspace location: '/Users/apple/Desktop/JenkinsJobs' (not using any variable)
2) Make sure no whitespaces in path
Unfortunately if the above will not work, I have no more ideas what may cause this, and suggest reporting the issue - see here: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/How+to+report+an+issue